# Does python has an equivalent to symbol objects in R language?

Tags: python, r

I have a background in regular programming languages such as python and C++. I have recently started using R language for some data analysis and I am having a hard time comprehending what are `symbol` and `expression` objects in R and why there is no need for an equivalent object in python or C++.

See the sample code below in R language:

```
z <- expression(x+y)
x <- 1
y <- 2
eval(z)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a mathematical expression or rather a R syntatically correct expression that can be evaluated. I do not know of an equivalent in python, since the parsing and evaluation is done with the function `eval` while in R the parsing and evaluation take two stages.

Take for example

python:

```
x = 1
y = 2
eval("x+y")
Out[376]: 3
```

Now with R, to do the same, we have:

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = parse(text="x+y")
eval(z)
[1] 3
```

You can see that the difference between the two is the parsing part. where in python, that is done within the eval function while in R, this is done independently.

Now the resulting object of parsing is what is called an `expression`:

```
class(z)
[1] "expression"
 typeof(z)
[1] "expression"
```

As you can see, the output  of parsing to get the specified language's object is just an `expression`.  This, when evaluated, gives you the object with respect to that language. Since `eval` in python does both parsing and evaluation into python objects, I do not think there is equivalent of expression in python

Comment: Okay, then I can think of `expression` as a string object that is syntactically correct, and can be evaluated later at some other time. But symbols are even more confusing as in `df %>% filter(col == 0)`, `col` is a symbol which haven't even been defined before. Any comments on how to think about the symbol?

Comment: @dvd8719 `expression` is not a string but rather a parsed object. You can think of symbols as math variables. For example in python, the package sympy has symbols and expressions. These are the ones available in R.

Comment: I agree with your comment about `expression`. But I don't think `symbols` are like math variables. in my example of `df %>% filter(col == 0)`, `col` is the name of the column in `df` that we are trying to set a filter on. The confusing part is that we don't define `col` anywhere before we use it. We only load `df` from a data set and there exists a column with name `col`. I rambled too much and I am not sure if you are able to follow my thoughts. :D

Comment: @dvd8719 `col` is a variable that is only available within the environment of `df`.  This is all about lazy evaluations in R and it is under the scope of ADVANCED R. so I bet you should go through lazy evaluations to understand in depth

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you point out to a good reference for lazy evaluation?

Comment: @dvd8719. Just google lazy evaluations in R and there will be a bunch of insormation. I have not studied widely on that area

Comment: @dvd8719 I think you would benefit from reading the [Metaprogramming section](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html) in the Advanced R book that I linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Expressions in R are (primarily) used to write functions that capture their input without evaluating it straight away [[1]](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/expressions.html). A typical use case is to then change the context in which the captured input is evaluated. This type of “non-standard evaluation” can make interactive analysis code faster and more natural to write.

Here’s an example that takes a data argument and evaluates the second argument inside it (essentially the base function `with()`):

```r
inside <- function(data, expr) {
  eval(substitute(expr), data)
}

df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2), y = c(3, 4))
```

Without the ability to capture expressions, the following would fail, as `x` and `y` are not defined in the global scope, but are only present as columns in the data frame `df`:

```r
inside(df, x + y)
#> [1] 4 6
```

I'm not aware of this concept existing in Python, and neither do I feel confident to comment on whether or not there is "no need for [it]" there; but I hope this helps with understanding how they fit in R.

For more details, a good place to start would be the [metaprogramming section](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html) in Advanced R.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can use [Lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html), which are actually one-line functions:

```
In [1]: z = lambda: x + y

In [2]: x = 1

In [3]: y = 2

In [4]: z()
Out[4]: 3

In [5]: x = 4

In [6]: z()
Out[6]: 6
```

The above declaration of `z` is equivalent to:

```
def z():
    return x + y
```

Because they are functions, scope rules apply. Therefore, `z()` only worked because x and y are global variables.

Comment: Isn't `lambda` more like anonymous functions in R?

Comment: @d.b I'm not so familiar with R, but by the looks of it, yes it is. It may be a different way of achieving the same goal.